# Triggering an image refresh within a particular row of ListView based on activity transistion event

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom `ListView` within an Activity A, each row comprising of some ImageViews and TextViews.

First I navigate from Activity A to Activity B by using `startActivityForeResult()`  method. I have succeeded in tracking the return from Activity B to Activity A through `onBackPressed()` method.

Now, I want to trigger a image refresh (change of image based on some data values) for *one of the ImageViews* **within a particular ListView row**, when I return from another activity B, based on some data values set in that second activity.

Currently I figured out that I can pass the *position value* of the ListView row through the transition from A to B and back to A, but I am stuck on the further implementation.

How should I go about this? Most of the posts I see here talk about triggering image change from within an `OnClickListener` for that ListView row. However, I need to do this based on the event of returning from Activity B to Activity A.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you should never access a single `ListView` row and update it's `View` (There are ways to do it by keeping a reference to the displayed views, but you shouldn't).

What you should do is:

1. When you get the result from Activity B, you set the data for the
   adapter in activity A for the row you want to update (or when you are doing `onResume()`).
2. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for that adapter.
3. The list will update and if that row is visible it will update
   accordingly.

There is no good reason not to follow this and update just one row (because if it takes too long to update the views, it means you are doing something wrong).

Comment: So I have to maintain a reference for that adapter?

Comment: I usually do because it is simpler, but ListView has getAdapter() in it so you don't have to.

Comment: how to approach if the row is not visible?

Comment: The great thing is that you don't care if the row is visible or not. You update the data and the list is smart enough to know whether is should update or not update the views.

Comment: But i want it to update even when currently the row is not visible, so that when I scroll down to the updated row, the change should be seen for that row

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to make it work based on this answer :)